# Does same null space imply same row space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices with the same domain, $R^n$. If $\text{Null}(A) = \text{Null}(B)$, then is it true that $\text{Row}(A) = \text{Row}(B)$? From my understanding, this is true as every x in the shared null space is orthogonal to span of both Row(A) and Row(B). Am I correct?

Comment: It's not enough to say the row space is orthogonal to the null space - it is *the orthogonal complement* (and hence uniquely determined).

Comment: What's the difference? So does Row(A) = Row(B)?

Comment: For example, $\{ 0 \}$ and ${\rm Row} A^\perp$ are both orthogonal to ${\rm Row} A = {\rm Row} B$, but they are not equal in general. But, you can show that ${\rm Nul} A = {\rm Row} A^\perp = {\rm Row} B^\perp = {\rm Nul} B$.

Comment: Ah makes sense. But what then about Row(A) and Row(B)?

Comment: Well, ${\rm Row}(A)={\rm Nul}(A)^\perp$ and ${\rm Row}(B)={\rm Nul}(B)^\perp$ and ${\rm Nul}(A)={\rm Nul}(B)$ so...

Comment: LOL, I swear I've been thinking about this for about twenty minutes... 3 hours of sleep messes with the mind...